# Serializing a list of Object using Json.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a object model as below to which i'm binding data retrieving from the database.

```
public class Student
{
    public virtual string serialNumber
    { set; get;}

    public virtual string studentFname
    { set; get;}

    public virtual string studentLname
    { set; get;}

    public virtual string studentAge
    { set; get;}
}
```

There will be number of objects as there are multiple student data's so i should ideally bind the objects to a Collection preferably a LIST<> and my requirement is I should transport this list of object to another code(Android). I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and am trying to convert the object into json. But if I want to pass the list to another code i should convert the entire list as Json. Accordingly what should be my return type and how to serialize it for my code below

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class GetData
{
    public List<Student> getData()
    {
        List<Student> stData = new List<Student>();
        Student st = new Student();
        string con = "Data Source=MK-001/PC; Initial Catalog=Inventory; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=sqlserver;";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            string query = "Select * from StudentData";
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    st.serialNumber = reader["Serial Number"].ToString();
                    st.studentFname = reader["Student Fname"].ToString();
                    st.studentLname = reader["Student Lname"].ToString();
                    st.studentAge = reader["Student Age"].ToString();

                    //Is this the correct way??
                    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(set);
                    stData.Add(jsonObject);
                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        //Im returning a list here. How to bind this to a json and what should be return type as per the change made?
        return stData;
    }
}
```

Comment: return type should be string and the recipient side may construct it back as Json object or fill as List

Comment: so instead of var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(set); i should make it as string jsonObject =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(set)?

Comment: Yes mate. http://surajdeshpande.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/json-net-examples/

Comment: And even if i convert object value into a string, how can i handle the list of objects?

Comment: The question is not clear - did you checked the link I gave you?

Comment: @ codebased thanks  lot for the article provided It says a lot, but yes out of curiosity. If i convert the entire list as string, will i be able to access it with ease in another code(say Android)?.. Thanks

Comment: Yes mate, mostly all platform provides you an option to read json as objects.

Comment: For android you will use:  
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json); See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: @codebased needless to say if i find the answer correct it would be a tick for sure :). But as your post are really helpful i would not hesitate to ask you this. Deserializing a string back to JSONObject looks fine from one of the link you provided, but in my case this string has a list of object values. So will i face any difficulty in getting all Student object values back from the list??

Comment: I mean the post looks perfect for just a single JSONObject, but what about the list of STudent Object in my case?

Comment: It will not be a problem as the return would be an array for android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try this:

https://surajdeshpande.com/2013/10/01/json-net-examples/

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList);
```

Deserialize JSON to an Object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks codebased, really helpful. People looking for the answer also go through the solution @Yuval provided. That is quite helpful too.

Comment: Actually it should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonString);` if you serialized a `List<User>`

Comment: The link is dead. This is why the answer should actually answer the question, instead of linking to an external page.

Answer (score 3):

You should serialize your `List<Student>` after you finish loading them from your DB;

```
string jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stData);
```

and return the json string from your method:

```
public string getData()
{  
     // Do stuff
     return jsonString // this is your List<Student> serialized to json
}
```

And on the other side, deserialize it back to a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONArray studentList = new JSONArray(studentJson);
```

Comment: @ Yuval thanks a lot for the answer. But as there are multiple student data in Database i may have to return a list of objects or as @Codebased said i should convert the entire list as string and return the string instead. But if i do so how will i deserialize the string back to object?

Comment: Look at my code. I serialize stData which is a `List<Student>` and deserialize it on the other end

Comment: I didn't notice your other side was android. Modified my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Really helpful answer, but deserializing  seems as if it is creating Json object from the returned JsonString(which contains a list of Student object). But if it contains 100's of data objects how will this be handled on other side? Shouldn't it be converted back to list of JSONObject?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with java types. Try a `JSONArray` maybe?

Comment: I'm marking codebased answer as a answer as he provided post which may be helpful for newbies like me but needless to say even you answer is equally important...Thanks a lot